# Post AJAX call to resource controller's store method not working in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to store the form data in database through resource controller using post type ajax request but it is giving me error **POST http://localhost:8000/reservations 405 (Method Not Allowed)**

### AJAX

```
    $('#btn_add').click(function() {
      $('#user-form').ajaxSubmit({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '{!! url($route)!!}', //it's http://localhost:8000/reservations
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
          success: function(result) {
          console.log(result);
              $('#user_up_stat').addClass('modal-' + result['type']);
              $('#user_up_stat_title').html(result['status']);
              $('#user_up_stat_msg').html(result['msg']);
              $('#user_up_stat').modal('show');
          },
          error: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            }
      });
  });
```

### Controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $this->check();
    if($request->name == null || $request->name == '')
        return ['status'=>'Error','type'=>'danger','msg'=>"Unable to Update enter a valid name."];
    if($request->email == null || $request->email == '')
        return ['status'=>'Error','type'=>'danger','msg'=>"Unable to create select a valid email."];
    if($request->phone == null || $request->phone == '')
        return ['status'=>'Error','type'=>'danger','msg'=>"Unable to update enter a valid phone number."];
    if($request->address == null || $request->address == '')
        return ['status'=>'Error','type'=>'danger','msg'=>"Unable to update enter a valid address."];
    if($request->checkin_date == null || $request->checkin_date == '')
        return ['status'=>'Error','type'=>'danger','msg'=>"Unable to update enter a valid check in date."];
    if($request->checkout_date == null || $request->checkout_date == '')
        return ['status'=>'Error','type'=>'danger','msg'=>"Unable to update enter a valid check out date."];
    if($request->room_id == null || $request->room_id == '')
        return ['status'=>'Error','type'=>'danger','msg'=>"Unable to Update enter a valid room id."];
    if($request->card_name == null || $request->card_name == '')
        return ['status'=>'Error','type'=>'danger','msg'=>"Unable to update enter a valid card name."];
    if($request->card_number == null || $request->card_number == '')
        return ['status'=>'Error','type'=>'danger','msg'=>"Unable to update enter a valid card number."];
    if($request->expiry_date == null || $request->expiry_date == '')
        return ['status'=>'Error','type'=>'danger','msg'=>"Unable to update enter a valid expiry date."];
    $reservations=new Reservation();
    $reservations->name = $request->name;
    $reservations->email = $request->email;
    $reservations->address = $request->address;
    $reservations->checkin_date = $request->checkin_date;
    $reservations->checkout_date = $request->checkout_date;
    $reservations->room_id = $request->room_id;
    $reservations->card_name = $request->card_name;
    $reservations->card_number = $request->card_number;
    $reservations->expiry_date = $request->expiry_date;

    if($request->has('card_type'))
        $reservations->card_type = $request->card_type;

    $reservations->save();
    return ['status'=>'Success','type'=>'success','msg'=>'Reservation updated successfully.'];
 }
```

### Route

```
Route::resource('/reservations' , 'ReservationsController');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax request to store function of resource controller not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062251/ajax-request-to-store-function-of-resource-controller-not-working)

Comment: try Route::resource('reservations' , 'ReservationsController');

Comment: is your backend on a different port?

Comment: @FrankProvost what do you mean?

Comment: Try removing the `/` in your route.

Comment: you are doing a post to localhost:8000 - if your frontend is hosted on a different port it might occur that you are actually doing an "options" request in before the actual post. What does your header say in your network traffic for the failed request?

Comment: @TaylorFoster did that still same error

Comment: @FrankProvost but my other functionality is working